# C#: how to get an object by the name stored in String?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

is it possible in C# to get an object by name?

i.e. get this.obj0 using

```
string objectName = "obj0";
executeSomeFunctionOnObject(this.someLoadObjectByName(objectName));
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how this name should map to the object? Are you looking for an object instance, or a type? Do you want existing instances, or create new ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not.

Objects don't have names - variables do. An object may be referenced by any number of variables: zero, one or many.

What you *can* do, however, is get fields (static or instance variables) by name (using [`Type.GetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield.aspx)) and get the values of those fields (for a specific instance, if you're using instance variables).

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might also want to consider a dictionary from names to objects.

Comment: It's rare that someone clearly says no it can't be done so you can move on and look at a different approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, not all objects have a Name property (for starters).

But you can store objects of interest in a `Dictionary<string, object>`. You could also get a Control by name, the exact method would depend on the UI library.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an object by name.  Using reflection, though, you can all fields and properties of a class (by name, if you want).  If your object is stored in a field level variable or in a property, then this will give you what you want:

```
Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
FieldInfo[] myFields = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

PropertyInfo[] myproperties = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

You can also call GetField and GetProperty (singular) and pass in a string to have it return a single member matching that name (make sure to check for null).

Read these pages for more information on reflection methods of use in this situation:

[GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty(VS.71).aspx)

[GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332492(VS.71).aspx)

[GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332472(VS.71).aspx)

[GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332470(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think what you are looking for is [Reflection.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx)

You can see a good example here: 
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-reflection-to-get-object-information

As said before - objects don't have names but you can traverse the objects and get their type and act accordingly.

This blog [here](http://blog.guymahieu.com/2006/07/11/deep-reflection-of-properties-propertyreflector/) shows a real good example of traversing and usage of reflection.

This should be a good start for sure.
Enjoy!